# How to generate set array of object in post request in Swagger with Laravel?

Tags: php, swagger, laravel-5.5

I am trying to generate array of object in Laravel-5.5 Swagger using body request in Laravel Model.

How should i achieve desired output ??

```
[
  {
    "user_name": "string",
    "education": [
      {
        "degree": [
          {
            "year": "string",
            "name": "string"
          },
          {
            "year": "string",
            "name": "string"
          }
        ],
        "hobby": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "string"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

can anyone please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer below and solved your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "User" model you just need to put this below code.

```
/**
 *  @SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="User",
 *      type="array",
 *      @SWG\Items(
 *          type="object",
 *          @SWG\Property(type="string", property="user_name", description="User name"),
 *          @SWG\Property(type="array", property="education", description="Education",
 *              @SWG\Items(
 *                  @SWG\Property(property="degree", type="object",
 *                      type="array",
 *                      @SWG\Items(
 *                          @SWG\Property(property="year", type="string"),
 *                          @SWG\Property(property="name", type="string"),
 *                      ),
 *                  ),
 *                  @SWG\Property(property="hobby", type="object",
 *                      type="array",
 *                      @SWG\Items(
 *                          @SWG\Property(property="type", type="string"),
 *                          @SWG\Property(property="description", type="string"),
 *                      ),
 *                  ),
 *              ),
 *          ),
 *      ),
 * ),
 */
class User extends Model
{
   //
}
```

> In above code while you send request that time you just need to edit.
>   After copy paste after immidiate degree object with ",". Then you can
>   pass multiple object in array.
>
> Thanks,

Comment: let me implement

Comment: Okay, If you get stuck then let me know same. so I can help you more about swagger.

Comment: Yes, you will get json response from this swagger comment code in laravel.